# How to resolve SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character in prestodb on linux?

Tags: linux, presto

I need to fetch data from the database where id_1 starts with E.
The code was working fine before I added the Where clause for the above constarint

```
sql = "select inserted_at, id1, id2, id3 from data where inserted_at<=" + str(start_date_time) + " and " \
                       "inserted_at>=" + str(end_date_time) + " " \ 
                       "and" "where id1 like %E%"
```

I get this error.

```
"inserted_at>=" + str(end_date_time) + " " \ 
                                                ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Comment: Are you using Python?

Comment: Yes. I have used python

Comment: make sure there aren't any white space chars after each `"\"` char. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem is being caused by placing enescaped date/datetime literals in your query.  You *could* fix this immediate problem by placing single quotes around `start_date_time`, but a better long term fix would be to use a prepared statement:

```
sql = "select inserted_at, id1, id2, id3 from data where inserted_at between ? and ? and id1 like '%E%'"
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(sql, (start_date_time, end_date_time,))
```